# 'Unable to delete property' on Safari when trying to delete dataset attribute in strict mode

Tags: javascript, dom, safari

Consider following code:

```js
(function () {
  'use strict';
  delete document.body.dataset.state;
})();
```

where body `dataset` is empty. Safari treats all DOMStringMap values — well, I guess so — as `ReadOnly`, and their `enumerable`, `configurable` and `writable` descriptor values are all set to `false`. This causes the `TypeError: Unable to delete property` to appear in the mentioned above example.

But in Chrome dataset property descriptor values are set to `true` (can be checked with `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor()`), and deleting inexistent attribute does not throw the error.

So, what behavior is correct? The spec says about [readonly dataset](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#elements-in-the-dom:dom-dataset), but [writable DOMStringMap](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#domstringmap), so I assume dataset properties must be deletable. Am I missing something?

Comment: Without looking into it deeper, just as a reminder, the spec isn't absolute and defined down to the detail, a surprising amount of things is implementation-specific.

Comment: The spec does not seem to say what syntax should be supported to remove a dataset attribute.  The general public consensus among developers using other browsers is to clear the value by setting it to an empty string or to use `delete`, but there does not seem to be a written standard on this.  My personal opinion is that Safari is probably wrong here, but it is what it is if you have to make code work with it.

Comment: Found any solution to this?

Comment: @AnkurAggarwal nope, using `removeAttribute('data-whatever')` for this.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*where body `dataset` is empty*" - can you post the respective markup?

Comment: Did you call `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor` for the `dataset` property or for the `state` property? It's not exactly clear from your question

Comment: You could always try `document.body.removeAttribute('data-foo')`.

Answer (score 2):

Its probably because of strict mode.

> Third, strict mode makes attempts to delete undeletable properties
>   throw (where before the attempt would simply have no effect):

```
'use strict';
delete Object.prototype; // throws a TypeError
```

You may want to take a look at [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)

Also you can try  set object value to undefined, its a little hairy but works..